# Comparar nombre de los campos de un dataframe en python con pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

main_file_path = '../input/train.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(main_file_path)
main_file_path2 = '../input/test.csv'
df2 = pd.read_csv(main_file_path2)

df1.columns
df2.columns
```

¿Cómo puedo conocer los campos que tienen en común y los campos que difieren en ambos `dataframe`?

Comment: Bienvenido, @Michael Merchan , podrías personalizar tu pregunta , vista esto [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), utiliza las herramientas que te da stack , como snippet, destacador de texto , para que sea bien recibida por la comunidad.Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, en este caso parece que ya lo modificaron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

la manera más directa que se me ocurre.

Campos comunes:

```
set(df1.columns.values).intersection(set(df2.columns.values))
```

Campos en `df1` y no en `df2`:

```
set(df1.columns.values).difference(set(df2.columns.values))
```

y, al revés, campos en `df2` pero no en `df1`:

```
set(df2.columns.values).difference(set(df1.columns.values))
```

Comment: Si pude realizar la comparación, gracias

Comment: @MichaelMerchan considera aceptar la respuesta si consideras que resuelve adecuadamente tu problema, es la forma de agradecer el trabajo  de quien te responde y ayuda a otros usuarios con tu mismo problema a identificar una buena solución al mismo. Para saber cómo hacerlo y cómo funciona mírate el siguiente enlace: [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/15089) . Un saludo.